# How to implement a 'light Entity' version with JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

Have a "full Entity" class:

```
@Entity(name = "vacancy_dec_to_words")
public class VacancyDescriptionToWords {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "vacancy_description_id")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private VacancyDescription vacancyDescription;

    @JoinColumn(name = "words_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Words words;

    @Column(name = "qty")
    private int qty;

    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date date;

    //...getters and setters
```

In some methods I need use only 2 column from this database: `word_id` and `qty`

I try the follow way:

**Projections**
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections

```
public interface QtyWords {
    Long getWords();
    Integer getQty();
}
```

**JpaReposytory:**

*Query, that I use tested and it workable, I use him in `JpaRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface SmallVDTWRepository extends JpaRepository<VacancyDescriptionToWords, Long> {

@Query(nativeQuery = true,
        value = "SELECT sum(qty), words_id FROM vacancy_desc_to_words WHERE vacancy_description_id IN (" +
                "SELECT id FROM vacancy_description WHERE vacancy_id IN (" +
                "SELECT id FROM vacancy WHERE explorer_id = :exp))" +
                "GROUP BY words_id")
List<QtyWords> getDistinctWordsByExplorer(@Param("exp") long exp);
}
```

But I get some interesting result when I get list of entities:

```
    List<QtyWords> list = vdtwService.getByExplorerId(72);
```

I am not get any exceptions, but I have the list with are unknowns objects. This objects contains my data, which I need(`qty` and `words_id`), but I cannot get them from him.

[image]

Can I use this method (`Projection`) to implement this task and, in general, how to correctly implement the 'Light Entity' in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring provides two mechanisms that can be used to limit data to be fetched.

### [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections)

Projections can help you to reduce data, retrieved from database, by setting what exactly attributes you want to fetch.

### Example:

```
@Entity
class Person {
    @Id UUID id;
    String firstname, lastname;
    @OneToOne
    Address address;
}

@Entity
static class Address {
    @Id UUID id;
    String zipCode, city, street;
}

interface NamesOnly {
    String getFirstname();
    String getLastname();
}

@Repository
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, UUID> {
    Collection<NamesOnly> findByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

### [Entity graph](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph)

Annotation `EntityGraph` can help you to reduce amount of queries to database, by setting what exactly related entities you need to fetch.

### Example:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "GroupInfo.detail", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("members"))
public class GroupInfo {
    @Id UUID id;
    @ManyToMany //default fetch mode is lazy.
    List<GroupMember> members = new ArrayList<GroupMember>();
}

@Repository
public interface GroupRepository extends CrudRepository<GroupInfo, String> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "GroupInfo.detail", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    GroupInfo getByGroupName(String name); //Despite of GroupInfo.members has FetchType = LAZY, it will be fetched because of using EntityGraph
}
```

There are two types of `EntityGraph`:

1. `EntityGraphType.LOAD` - is used to specify an entity graph, attributes that are specified by attribute nodes of the entity graph are treated as `FetchType.EAGER` and attributes that are not specified are treated according to their specified or default `FetchType`.
2. `EntityGraphType.FETCH` - is used to specify an entity graph, attributes that are specified by attribute nodes of the entity graph are treated as `FetchType.EAGER` and attributes that are not specified are treated as `FetchType.LAZY`.

**PS:** Also remember that you can set lazy fetch type: `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` and JPA will not fetching child entities when parent is being fetched.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept you answer, when successfuly use you tiph

Comment: When I try use `EntityGraph`, I get exception `No identifier specified for entity: SmallVDTW`. But, when I use `Projections` https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections - all right, but(!) I cannot get my data from result set. I try show that in my edited question

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi, oh, I see the point. `EntityGraph` is intended to be used with entities only, but you need projections. But I can not realize, why you are not able to get data from result of `vdtwService.getByExplorerId(72)`? I see that you've got a collection of proxies, but you must be able to work with that proxies as with `QtyWords` objects.

Comment: I am question the same: "why I are not able to get data from result of vdtwService.getByExplorerId(72)? " =).`

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi provide a code you use to read it, with short explanation what is wrong(e.g. why you cant do this: vdtwService.getByExplorerId(72).get(0).getQty())

Comment: Just "zero". You can see in the screenshot: the list of objects does not include `VacancyDescriptionToWords`. It contains objects with database results. But not with my "light essence"