# Eager fetch an specific lazy property for a particular object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following model:

```
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Bar bar;

}
```

Using `Entity Framework` in .NET in a similar situation, I could eagerly bring the `Bar` property with something like:

```
context.Foo.Include(f => f.bar).First()
```

Is there anything equivalent with Hibernate?

My situation is that I'm saving an object with a lazy property into a session in my server. Then when I retrieve the session properties, I cannot access the lazy property for the Hibernate Session is already gone. I cannot put this property as `EAGER` because it is inherited from a `@MappedSuperclass` used by a lot of other classes.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. JPA [EntityGraph](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching-entity-graph):

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "foo")
   @NamedEntityGraph(name = "foo.bar",
           attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("bar")
   )
   public class Foo {

       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       private Bar bar;

   }

   Foo foo = entityManager.find(
       Foo.class,
       id,
       Collections.singletonMap(
           "javax.persistence.fetchgraph",
           entityManager.getEntityGraph("foo.bar")
       )
   );
   ```

   You can see another example and more detail explanation [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361445/how-to-implement-ligh-entity-version-with-jpa-repository/53361956#53361956).
2. [Hibernate profiles](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching-profile):

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "foo")
   @FetchProfile(
       name = "foo.bar",
       fetchOverrides = {
           @FetchProfile.FetchOverride(
               entity = Foo.class,
               association = "bar",
               mode = FetchMode.JOIN
           )
       }
   )
   public class Foo {
       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       private Bar bar;
   }


   session.enableFetchProfile("foo.bar");
   Foo foo = session.byId(Foo.class).load(id);
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this EntityGraph :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JPQL query with `FETCH JOIN`:

```
List<Foo> l = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT f FROM Foo f JOIN FETCH f.bar", Foo.class)
    .getResultList();
```

In this way all `Foo` class instances will be loaded with all `Bar` instances already fetched. You can tailor the query to fit your needs.